# How to implement a protocol which has same name as another class

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

In Objective C, the @interface and @protocol can have same names. How to create a class in Swift to adopt only the protocol?

[Nimbus NICellFactory.h](https://github.com/jverkoey/nimbus/blob/master/src/models/src/NICellFactory.h)

```
@interface NICellObject : NSObject <NICellObject>

// Designated initializer.
- (id)initWithCellClass:(Class)cellClass userInfo:(id)userInfo;
- (id)initWithCellClass:(Class)cellClass;

+ (id)objectWithCellClass:(Class)cellClass userInfo:(id)userInfo;
+ (id)objectWithCellClass:(Class)cellClass;

@property (nonatomic, strong) id userInfo;

@end
```

How to adopt the **protocol NICellObject** without subclass **class NICellObject**

Comment: I understand that the issue comes from a framework but none the less isn't it really bad practice to have the same name for a protocol and delegate? So wouldn't it be a bad framework?

Comment: @Minimi it's very common in some open source cocoa apps, like Adium

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you import the objective c class into swift, "Protocol" will be automatically append to the name of the protocol. So you should just adopt the XXXXXProtocol.

I just tried it in my local project. In your case NICellObjectProtocol.

### OLD ANSWER BEFORE EDIT

You take it wrong, they are two different thing with the same name. One is protocol named NICellObject, and a class also named NICellObject.

> How to implement two protocols in swift with one protocol also is a
>   class In Nimbus there is NICellObject which is a protocol and a class,
>   see the code below. There must have many same cases.

From this link, https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingBasics.html.

> Some protocols group a number of unrelated methods (rather than create
>   several separate small protocols). These protocols tend to be
>   associated with a class that is the principal expression of the
>   protocol. In these cases, the convention is to give the protocol the
>   same name as the class.

And it is not possible to do this in Swift. I can't find the document saying so, but some hint From the language reference, declaration introduces a NEW name or contract into your program.

> “A declaration introduces a **new name or construct into your program**.
>   For example, you use declarations to introduce functions and methods,
>   variables and constants, and to define new, named enumeration,
>   structure, class, and protocol types. You can also use a declaration
>   to extend the behavior of an existing named type and to import symbols
>   into your program that are declared elsewhere.
>
> ”

摘录来自: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language”。 iBooks. https://itun.es/cn/jEUH0.l

Comment: I know `One is protocol named NICellObject, and a class also named NICellObject.`
I want `class A:BaseObject, NICellObject {}` .

Comment: awesome , How do you find it? it doesn't auto complete for me

Comment: It does auto complete for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Just add a `Protocol` suffix to the protocol name, to distinguish the **Class** and the **Protocol**:

```c
class A: BaseObject, NICellObjectProtocol { }
```